# Java: unparseable date exception error

Tags: java, simpledateformat

im not able to parse the string to date

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss.SSSZ");
        String date="2015-08-27T11:46:35.336Z";

        try {
            Date date1=mdyFormat1.parse(date);
            System.out.println(date1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

getting error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-08-27T11:46:35.336Z"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.connectm.onprocess.logincontroller.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues there :

1. `2015-08-27T11:46:35.336Z`,The colon (: ) between 46 and 35 , it should be . ( dot).As for the format  `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss.SSSZ")`. So it should be `2015-08-27T11:46.35.336Z`. And the Z which is the next problem.
2. And the Z at the end of the string is also wrong, it should be something like "2015-08-27T11:46.35.336-0800" to make it work. But if you still do n't understand the Z part please refer the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `mdyFormat1` object initialization changed from

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss.SSSZ");`

to

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String date="2015-08-27T11:46:35.336Z";

    try {
        Date date1=mdyFormat1.parse(date);
        System.out.println(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

> Thu Aug 27 11:46:35 CDT 2015

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, your formatting pattern failed to match your input data.

## java.time

Furthermore, you are using old outmoded classes that have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. In Java 8 and later they have been supplanted by the newly built-in java.time framework.

Your input data is in standard ISO 8601 format. That format is used by default in java.time for parsing and generating string representations of date-time values. So, no need to specify a formatter.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-08-27T11:46:35.336Z" );
String output = instant.toString();
```

You can assign a time zone if need be.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```